# Android Canvas update line coords

Tags: android, canvas, graphics, draggable

I have drawn a line starting at point A (Always zero) and ending at point B using
canvas.drawLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);

But point B is draggable, so i want to update canvas line xEnd and yEnd to B position when its dragged. The problems is that when i update line coords it thorows an error with just 1 line explanation:

"Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10c in tid 5638 (xample.launcher)" It says xample.launcher but my packageName is com.example.launcher, i don't know if problem is there

Here it goes my code.

**DrawView (point B)**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView {

String label;
int color, direction, x, y;
View view;
DrawPath path;

public DrawView(){

}

public DrawView(String label, int color, int direction, int x, int y, View view){
    this.label = label;
    this.color = color;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.view = view;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public int getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public int getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public void setDirection(int direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public View getView() {
    return view;
}
public void setView(View view) {
    this.view = view;
}
public DrawPath getPath() {
    return path;
}
public void setPath(DrawPath path) {
    this.path = path;
}



}
```

**DrawPath (Line between point A to Point B)**

```
    package com.example.launcher;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

    public class DrawPath extends View{

    int color, x, y;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;

    public DrawPath(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.canvas = canvas;
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        Log.e("THIS X, THIS Y", this.x + " " + this.y);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, this.x, this.y, paint);
        invalidate();
    }


    public void setColor(int color){
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }

    public void setXValue(int x){
        this.x = x;
        if(canvas != null){
            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, this.x, this.y, paint);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public float getXValue(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setYValue(int y){
        this.y = y;
        if(canvas != null){
            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, this.x, this.y, paint);
            invalidate();
        }

    }

    public float getYValue(){
        return this.y;
    }



    }
```

**And finally my onTouch Event**

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
        final int X = (int)event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int)event.getRawY();


        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xDelta = X - (draw.getX());
                yDelta = Y - (draw.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   

                params.setMargins((X - xDelta), (Y - yDelta), 0, 0);
                draw.getPath().setXValue((X - xDelta));
                draw.getPath().setYValue((Y - yDelta));
                myView.setLayoutParams(params); 


                break;
            }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: don't call `invalidate()` inside `onDraw()` method